# Объясните как работает алгоритм с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как работает этот алгоритм, в особенности интересует 13,15,16,18 строки. Конечно ясно что он выводит номер последнего вхождения подстроки и количество таких вхождений. Но как он их обрабатывает?
Что это за магический код?
Уже второй день ищу как работают эти функции, но объяснение приведено для профессионалов.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string stroke = "";
string substroke= "";
cin >> stroke;
cin >> substroke;
int j = 0; // позиция
size_t k = 0;
for (string::size_type i = 0; i < stroke.length(); ++i) {
    j = j + 1;          // номер позиции последнего вхождения
    if (stroke[i] == substroke[0]) {
        if (stroke.substr(i, substroke.length()) == substroke)      {
            k = k + 1;                              // кол-во вхождений
            i += substroke.length() - 1;
        }
    }
}
cout << j << endl;
cout << k;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм идет из начала в конец исследуемой строки (условие цикла), пока не появится **первая буква** искомой подстроки (`stroke[i] == substroke[0]`). Как только появилась - с этого места (`i`) надеется найти слово (`stroke.substr(i, substroke.length()) == substroke`), если находится - увеличивает счетчики и передвигается на его конец, откуда снова ищет первую букву..., иначе итерируется дальше в поисках буквы.

Comment: Хорошо, но хотелось бы тогда уточнить, что делает вот эта строчка:
 i += substroke.length() - 1;

Comment: @АндрейМишунин, сдвигаем текущую позицию (`i`) на длину **найденного** слова, чтобы продолжить поиск уже **за** ним.